# Capturar item selecionado do DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um `DropDownList` com alguns itens, e fiz um evento de clique pra pegar o que estiver selecionado e redirecionar para uma pagina, porem não esta funcionando direito, vejam:

```
switch(ddlMenu.SelectedValue){

            case "0":
             lblMensagem.Text = "Por favor, selecione uma opção valida";
                break;

            case "1":
                Response.Redirect("/pages/cadastro.aspx");
                break;

                case "2":
                Response.Redirect("/pages/consultas.aspx");
                break;

                case "3":
                Response.Redirect("/pages/detalhes.aspx");
                break;


}
```

O problema é que só funciona o item 0, e o item 1, o 2  e o 3 o resultado é como se fosse o item 0.

Alguém sabe porque esta errado?

Comment: Falei no post, so funciona o item 0, e o item 1, o 2 e o 3 processa a mensagem do 0, ou seja ao selecionar o 2 ou o 3, ele ta entrando na ação do 0.

Comment: Só com esse trecho não dá para ver problema algum, ele está correto. Talvez nem o 0 esteja sendo feito mas você não está percebendo.

Comment: @WarLock nao querera dizer `ddlMenu.SelectedIndex` e depois fazer o `switch` nesse valor (0, 1, 2, 3)?

Comment: Você ja debugou? E o que está vindo no `SelectedValue`?

Answer (score 1):

Veja como você esta carregando o *ddlMenu* utilize.

```
int32 idMenu=  ddlMenu.SelectedId();
```

e depois faça o *switch case* , provavelmente seu erro esta na forma que você esta carregando o `DropDownList` .

Answer (score 1):

O caso é que, no clique do dropdownlist, o valor selecionado ainda é *zero*, pois seu valor ainda não foi trocado.

Use o evento `SelectedIndexChanged()`, este irá ser disparado após o valor do dropdownlist ser alterado.